# How to act on the configuration of PHP in CLI to add pdo module

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, cloud-foundry

Currently I'm working on deploying a php (symfony)/MySQL application on cloud foundry. After deployment, when I connect in SSHto launch commands doctrines for the creation of the schema of the database I have this problem

```html
    vcap@5nkjb8jdl87:~/app$ ./php/bin/php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=prod
```

```html
 Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in /home/vcap/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/DriverManager.php on line 172
    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException] Attempted to load class "PDO" from the global namespace.Did you forget a "use" statement?
    doctrine:schema:create [--dump-sql] [--em [EM]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interactio
    -shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

```html
  vcap@5nkjb8jdl87:~/app$ ./php/bin/php -m
    [PHP Modules]
    bcmath
    calendar
    Core
    ctype
    date
    dom
    ereg
    filter
    hash
    iconv
    intl
    json
    libxml
    mhash
    mysqlnd
    pcre
    Phar
    posix
    Reflection
    session
    SimpleXML
    SPL
    sqlite3
    standard
    tokenizer
    xml
    xmlreader
    xmlwriter
    
    [Zend Modules]
    
    vcap@5nkjb8jdl87:~/app$
```

How to activate the php PDO module in ClI ?
Thank you for your help
cdt

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. A link to a screenshot is not acceptable, I'm afraid. You should provide the actual error code in the text of your question.

Comment: There are often 2 php.ini files. One used by Apache and another used by the CLI. Run `php -i` from your terminal and look for `Loaded Configuration File` This file must also have the PDO extension activated

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I run  this command from terminal 
'php -i | grep file' 
And i have this response
'Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /tmp/build/931e8e8a/binary-builder/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/php/5.5.38/lib 
Loaded Configuration File => (none)'
and  when i try to open php.ini with vi he create new file (I can not access the file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you SSH into an application using `cf ssh` the system unfortunately does not automatically configure the environment for you.  This causes things like PHP to function in different ways (often by failing) because environment variables that affect how PHP functions and where it looks for configuration are not set.

What you need to do to make things the same as when your application runs is to source the environment configuration first.  The process for doing this is documented [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#ssh-env).

However before doing that please keep in mind that executing the `.profile.d` and `.profile` scripts can have side-effects.  This is because both of these can be extended by your application.  This is typically done as a way to run commands prior to your application starting.  Make sure that these scripts are safe to run prior to executing the following commands!  If parts are not safe, then do not run them.  Just execute the commands that are safe.

For reference here, the process boils down to running these commands:

```
export HOME=/home/vcap/app
export TMPDIR=/home/vcap/tmp
cd /home/vcap/app
source /home/vcap/app/.profile.d/*.sh
source /home/vcap/app/.profile
```

This sources the `.profile.d` & `.profile` scripts which initialize the environment.

**UPDATE:**

A slightly easier way to do this is to run `cf ssh myapp -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"`.  This will open a bash shell and it lets the lifecycle launcher handle sourcing & setting up the environment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes it works, I understood
thanks a lot for your help @Daniel Mikusa
Thank you everyone for your participation

Answer (score 1):

you need to install `php-mysql`

```
apt-get install php-mysql
```

if you are using php7

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysql
```

find your php.ini file and search for `pdo_mysql`

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

remove ;

```
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Save the file and restart service and verify.

Comment: Thank you for your reply
I run  this command from terminal 
**php -i | grep file** 
And i have this response
**Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /tmp/build/931e8e8a/binary-builder/ports/x86_64-linux-gnu/php/5.5.38/lib 
Loaded Configuration File => (none)**
and  when i try to open php.ini with vi he create new file (I can not access the file)

Comment: if you are using ubuntu then "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini"

Comment: This won't work with Cloud Foundry.  Your app runs as a non-root user on CF and you cannot install arbitrary package with apt-get.